# Recommended way of repackaging proprietary deb packages, which include old system libraries

Tags: debian, ubuntu, libraries, packaging, deb

**Intro**

Long story short, in couple projects I'm using some stereo-cams. Unfortunately, manufacturer provides packages (rpm and [deb](http://kamiccolo.vhost.lt/SO/DepthSenseSDK-1.4.5-2151-amd64.deb)) for user-space drivers which are not exactly properly formatted (missing dependencies, other control information, etc.) To make it worse, it supposed to be ran on specific Linux distribution version (Ubuntu 12.04/Ubuntu 14.04), but it's bundled with outdated libraries i.e.:

> libturbojpeg.so
>
> libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0

One more thing, the original driver installs in `/opt/manufacturer/proprietary_driver/{bin, lib, etc}`.

So, for the sake of sane distribution, build and runtime of my projects I've decided to repackage this official manufacturer's mess. Blunt solution was just leaving all the libraries as-is, filling the required control information and adding something into `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/proprietary_driver.so.conf` like this:

> /opt/manufacturer/proprietary_driver/lib

**Issue**

Everything seems to work, **but** every single time doing `apt-get upgrade` I get this:

> /sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/manufacturer/proprietary_driver/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

Also, while reading [Debian maintainers guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/best-pkging-practices.html) I realized that putting stuff into `/opt` isn't compliant at all. Not to mention polluting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with libraries required only by some specific driver.

So to speak, I must be doing something wrong.

**Question**

Is there any other recommended or/and better way of dealing with proprietary binary Debian packages which does include old versions of various system libraries? I'd be very happy if suggested solution could be used for upstreaming the package in question at least into Debian and Ubuntu.